# Dynamic mysql connection and database

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic

I m trying to write a code of choose, connecting and accessing database but isn't working :X

```
$mysql_storage = true;

if($mysql_storage){

    $databases = array(

        array("localhost","glibet_login","#####","glibet_site")
    );

    foreach($databases as $database){

        $makeconnection = $database[1];
        ${$makeconnection} = mysql_connect($database[0],$database[1],$database[2]);
        mysql_select_db($database[3], $database[1]);

    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='marsalcorreialima@gmail.com'";
$littlequery = mysql_query($query, $glibet_login);
$littlefetch = mysql_num_rows($littlequery);
print $littlefetch;
```

Please tell me if this code at least makes sense

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/glibet/public_html/api/api_storage.php on line 16

EDIT [SOLVED]!

```
mysql_select_db($database[3], ${$makeconnection});
```

Comment: I strongly advise you to remove your MySQL login info...

Comment: see the answer of @YogeshSuthar, specially the part: stop using mysql_* its deprecated . use mysqli OR PDO.

Comment: Its random login info :)

Comment: y you want to connect to multiple database ?

Comment: in case of the database be on another server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should be

```
$makeconnection = $database[1];
${$makeconnection} = mysql_connect($database[0],$database[1],$database[2]);
mysql_select_db($database[3], ${$makeconnection});
```

And stop using `mysql_*` its deprecated . use `mysqli` OR `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have made the connection process a little complicated. It could have been more simple in the following way

```
$mysql_storage = true;
$makeconnection;

if($mysql_storage){
    $makeconnection = mysql_connect("localhost","glibet_login","#####");
    mysql_select_db("glibet_site", $makeconnection);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='marsalcorreialima@gmail.com'";
$littlequery = mysql_query($query, $makeconnection);
$littlefetch = mysql_num_rows($littlequery);
print $littlefetch;
```

Comment: Yeah but only for one or two connections :)